# I want to change default label YES NO of my checkbox radio_button from my f.input (form_for)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I'm starting using Rails.

In my form_for, I want to change label of default value YES / NO (which appear in my front view)

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <%= f.input :experience,
                   as: :radio_buttons,
                   label:"A t-il déjà saillie ?"  %>
           </div>
        </div>
```

Which option should I add to change label ? 
How can I display option in one line ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you using simple_form_for? I think so from as: :radio_buttons. If you are, try:

```
<%= f.input :experience, as: :radio_buttons, collection: [['0', 'false'], ['1', 'true']], label_method: :second, value_method: :first %>
```

You can probably infer the logic from that line. Make an array of arrays for your collection, each sub array containing first the value of the radio button, and then the label.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast answer. It works ! I understood the construction of the  line except the two "options"  : label_method  and value_method ?

Comment: Happy to help :) The label_method says which part of each array it uses to name the radio button, the text that displays next to it. The value_method says which part of the array it uses to submit as parameters when selected. So for the first array, the label_method is the second part, and it's labelled 'false'. When it's selected, its value is the first part of the array, '0' (which ruby reads as false)

Comment: I have one last question about displaying checkbox on the same line. I'm stuck, I tried almost everything. I added a class above the f.input block. I tried with display: flex, text-aligner-center, display:block ....     I moved the class inside the f.input (no result neither ...)

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? If so this should help: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/652

Comment: If not it gives an idea how to add classes to the form - unfortunately I'm strictly back end so can't help with styling :(

Comment: It dosen't work but thanks. I made another ticket :)